# Implement no-op functor using boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost-bind, boost-function

I have a function `void get(boost::function<void(void)> callback) { callback(); }`.
I want to make a call like `get(boost::bind(/* don't know what to put here*/));` without implementing any other functions, variables or structs, so that the callback does nothing.
Is it possible to implement such "no-op" callback in **C++03** ?

Usage of `boost::bind()` is prefered but not required - may be, there are some other tricks to achieve my goal.

Comment: Why not just use a no-op function, i.e. `void noop() {}`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, because that would mean implementing a function, which the OP explicitly wants to avoid.

Comment: ... or in cool C++11: `[](){}`

Comment: @avakar: Joachim is questioning the rationale around not implementing a simple noop function.

Comment: @avakar: "Why not?" is still a good question. If the OP has one bizarre restriction, then he may have others, so it would help to know where the restriction comes from.

Comment: @avakar, the simplest solution that is still working in older C++ versions is to use a no-op function. If abyss.7 can't do that, and is not able to use C++11 lambdas, then I think there is not much he can do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* use something like `boost::bind(std::plus<int>(), 0, 0)`, which should be optimised away to nothing.

It would make the code rather clearer if you relaxed your restriction and defined a no-op functor instead.

Comment: Does a `function<int(void)>` convert implicitly to `function<void(void)>`?

Comment: @SteveJessop: More or less. A `function<void(void)>` can accept a function object that takes no parameters but happens to return a value.

Comment: @SteveJessop: [Yes](http://ideone.com/V2VPE) (or at least, a functor that returns a value can be converted to a `boost::function` that doesn't).